# TBXML "class method tbXMLWithURL not found"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos, tbxml

i try to use TBXML and getting this error

> TBXML "class method +tbXMLWithURL not found"

I try as in the example

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    TBXML * tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/XML/note.xml"]] retain];    


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two different things in your code and in your error:

> TBXML "class method +**tbXMLWithURL** not found"

in your code:

> TBXML * tbxml = [[TBXML **tbxmlWithURL**:[NSURL
>   URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/XML/note.xml"]] retain];

From the TBXML [api](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/API.html):

> `- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)aURL` Instantiates a TBXML object then downloads and parses an XML file for the given URL. The following code
>   instantiates a TBXML object and parses the note.xml file from
>   w3schools.com.

What I think you want:

```
TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/XML/note.xml"]];
```

Comment: hi! Thank you for your answer! Now i get an error 'TBXML' may not respond to 'initWithURL' =(

Answer (score 2):

I am not that familiar with the TBXML, but at a brief look at the site, wouldn't:

```
TBXML* tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/XML/note.xml"]];
```

be better?